# Solana identify account transactions

Tags: solana

lets say I have an ecommerce website and I want to start accepting Solana.

The customer will fill the cart and proceed to the checkout page, there I can display a QR code where the user can scan to pay.

Now I want to know if the checkout has been paid so I can mark the order as paid, is there a good way to accomplish that? maybe using [Solana pay](https://docs.solanapay.com/spec#specification-transaction-request) I can pass a reference or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `validateTransfer` method to do that

> validateTransfer allows you to validate that the transaction signature found matches the transaction that you expected.

```js
try {
  await validateTransfer(connection, signature, {
    recipient: MERCHANT_WALLET,
    amount
  });

  // Update payment status
  paymentStatus = 'validated';
  console.log('✅ Payment validated');
  console.log(' Ship order to customer');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('❌ Payment failed', error);
}
```

check out the [solana documentation](https://docs.solanapay.com/core/transfer-request/merchant-integration#42-validating-the-transaction) for this

Comment: I was not aware of the reference! [transaction request](https://docs.solanapay.com/spec#specification-transaction-request) has a reference, then I was able to do what you said using the rpc api
cheers

Comment: glad i could help, keep eating glass!